# LINQ to XML - finding Elements inside only certain Parent/Ancestor Elements

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I'm pulling a string from a website.  (I know I'm pulling it correctly because I can print the entire string).  Source XML string:

```
<feed
xmlns = 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'
xmlns:cap = 'urn:oasis:names:tc:emergency:cap:1.1'
xmlns:ha = 'http://www.alerting.net/namespace/index_1.0'
>
<!-- http-date = Mon, 10 Oct 2013 17:29:01 GMT -->

<id>http://alerts.weather.gov/cap/la.atom</id>
<logo>http://alerts.weather.gov/images/xml_logo.gif</logo>
<generator>NWS CAP Server</generator>
<updated>2013-10-21T17:29:01+00:00</updated>
<author>
<name>w-nws.webmaster@noaa.gov</name>
</author>
<title>Current Watches, Warnings and Advisories for Louisiana Issued by the National Weather Service</title>
<link href='http://alerts.weather.gov/cap/la.atom'/>

<entry>
  <id>http://alerts.weather.gov/cap/la.atom</id>
  <updated>2013-10-21T17:29:01+00:00</updated>
  <author>
    <name>w-nws.webmaster@noaa.gov</name>
  </author>
  <title>There are no active watches, warnings or advisories</title>
  <link href='http://alerts.weather.gov/cap/la.atom'/>
  <summary>There are no active watches, warnings or advisories</summary>
</entry>
</feed>
```

What I'm trying to do is pull the text for the [title] element inside each [entry] (there'e only one in this example for simplicity, but there will be more later).  I do not want to pull the [title] from the [id] block.  How do I code the logic of inside [feed], find each [entry], inside [entry] find [title]? Once I get that, I can pull the value as a string just fine.

Right now, I've got:

```
    XElement root = XElement.Parse(xmlString);
    XNamespace ns = XNamespace.Get("http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom");

        String title = (String)
            (from elem in root.Descendants(ns + "title") select elem).First();

        // for testing purposes: Output element Value
        Console.WriteLine(title);

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
        Console.ReadKey();
```

which is writing the first [title] under [id] under [feed].

Thanks so much,
TK

EDIT to make new version legible: (thanks to Ronan)

```
XElement root = XElement.Parse(xmlString);

XNamespace ns = XNamespace.Get("http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom");

IEnumerable<XElement> xlist =
    root.Descendants("entry").Select(elem => elem.Descendants("title").Single());

foreach (XElement el in xlist)
    Console.WriteLine("Title: " + el.Value);

Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
Console.ReadKey();
```

So that's what it looks like now.

Comment: So did Ronan fix your problem or lead you in the right direction?  If so mark his answer as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're thinking backward by going down then up (title then check parent) instead just go down (get entries, then nest another select to find title on those)

```
Root.Descendants(ns + "entry")
    .Select(elem=>elem.Descendants(ns + "title").Single());
```

Comment: Thanks.  It took me a minute to figure out IEnumerable<XElement> xlist = your suggestion.  So it's giving me a list of elements (right?).  When I try the following print statement, it gives an empty set, nothing printed. `Foreach (XElement el in xlist)
Console.WriteLine("Title: " + el.Value);`  Suggestions?

Comment: You'd have to give the full code. Can't help if i don't see the definition of xlist. In my sample you simply end up with a list of title elements yes so your code looks right.

Comment: editted original post so you can read the new code.  When stepping through in debugger, it looks like xlist never changes from null.

Comment: @TK421 You are not dealing with the namespace.  I'll edit Ronan's answer to fix it with your variable.

Comment: Thanks Chuck.  Now that I realize I left out the ns when applying Ronan's guidance, yes, we're on our way.  Thanks to both of you.